# Laravel 8 - Programmatically run migration and seeder when database has no tables

Tags: php, laravel-8

After connecting to database, I want to programmatically run migration and seeder once the project detects that the database doesn't have any tables.
I think what I should do is inject the code below somewhere, but I don't know what file I should edit.

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    $init_met = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    set_time_limit(300);
    Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
    Artisan::call('db:seed');
    set_time_limit($init_met);
}
```

Or, is there an alternative way to do this instead of injecting the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd suggest you to look at composer scripts section - there are a lot of [events](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names) that could be used as trigger for your code. for example `post-autoload-dump` event fired after `composer dumpautoload` which is fired in most common calls like `install`, `update` or by itself. the benefit of using  composer events is that you don't need to check for existing tables on each request.

the most easy way to achieve this is to create [custom artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands)

```php
php artisan make:command PrepareEmptyDatabase
```

then in `app\Console\Commands\PrepareEmptyDatabase.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Exception;
use App\Http\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class PrepareEmptyDatabase extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:prepare-empty';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'check for users table and run migrations and seed if has not';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // don't forget to remove this if database user
        // don't have access to dba tables
        if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
            return Command::SUCCESS;
        }

        /* 
        // if your user doesn't have permission to access to dba tables
        // you can simply try to do any request to users table
        
        $needActions = false;
        try {
            User::first();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $needActions = true;
        }
        if (!$needActions) {
            return Command::SUCCESS;
        }
        */
        $init_met = ini_get('max_execution_time');
        set_time_limit(300);
        Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
        set_time_limit($init_met);
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

and the last step is tie this command with composer event, so in `composer.json`

```php
"scripts": {    
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover",
      "@php artisan db:prepare-empty"
    ]
  },
```

now any time you install/update composer dependencies or just run `composer dumpatoload` application will run your custom command. or you can stick with any of provided in composer docs event on your taste

---

###### about running the same code after `npm run dev`

i'm not quite sure about place to search, guess its about webpack events, but your question tagged with `laravel` so i assume you're using [laravel-mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#main-content) and there are [event hooks](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/event-hooks.md)

quick googling says that nodejs can run bash scripts using [nodejs child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```js
// webpack.mix.js
const exec = require('child_process')
// or import exec from 'child_process'
mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
// other configs
  .after(() => {
    exec.execSync('php artisan db:prepare-empty')
  })
```

pay attention that this code will run on any mix even including `npm run prod` for example and i don't actually understand why do you need it in frontend build event (if only for testing purpose and even then its questionable)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Another question, how can I call it everytime I compile the project (npm run dev)?

Comment: @rhemmuuu, please check updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, it also works. The reason for this is that I'm trying to clone my project to a shared folder on a different network and I have problems with accessing the command prompt, saying UNC paths are not supported, so I thought I'll just do it programmatically. Anyway, the migration and seed will not run if the database has users table already so I think it's safe.